# Setting encode for qstring export result

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dynamic-library

How I can export from library function UTF8 encoded string?

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) QString Test()
{
    QString tmp = "日本";
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: what compiler? The source file is UTF-8? I don't remember but, I think, visual studio only suports ascii or UCS-2 encoded files. It does compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings( QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8") );
```

helped.